# request time relation with network speed?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

I have network speed of 4 Mbps(Mega bits per sec) at both sides i.e. client and data center side. It means network can deliver max 4 Mega bits per second. For 1 Mbps it will be 1 Mega bits per second.  So this ISP network speed just tells how much max traffic it can serve in a sec.

Now consider I have send 100 Kb request to server , will it take the same time to reach to server be it 1Mbps or 4 Mbps ISP network speed as both speed says they can deliver 1 Mb or 4Mb data in sec and 100Kb is much lower than that?

So any request smaller than 1 Mbps will take more or less same time even with high network speed  like 4/8 Mbps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data on a network is not transferred in monolithic *n*-Mbps chunks that come once per second. It's a nearly continuous flow of bits. So you can think of 4Mbps as being 4 bits per microsecond or 4kbits per millisecond. So a 100kbit file would traverse a 4Mbps LAN in approximately 25ms, or a 1Mbps LAN in about 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

4Mb would usually be quicker, but as you say it might be the same (negible) since the file is so small. Doing some math yourself will likely confirm it